# How to read json data from list of URLs and tidy it into a dataframe?

Tags: r, json, url

I am using the help of https://ipstack.com to geocode IP addresses and am having a difficult time trying to geocode all 1200 addresses in a short amount of time.

With R, I've collected the URLs into a list (e.g. `http://api.ipstack.com/[IP address]?access_key=[access key]`) and can use `read_json` to read the json data of each URL. But I've not been able to develop a loop to extract the data from each URL.

```
library(RCurl)
library(jsonlite)

x <- c("http://api.ipstack.com/178.140.119.217?access_key=[access_key]", "http://api.ipstack.com/68.37.21.125?access_key=[access_key]", "http://api.ipstack.com/68.10.255.89?access_key=[access_key]")

read_json(x)
Error in file(path) : invalid 'description' argument
```

I'm looking for a solution that will be able to read multiple IP addresses and then attach the information to a dataframe.

*Edit 1: Still stuck, but I'm making some progress with the loop,

```
library(RCurl)
library(jsonlite)

url_lst = as.character(df$URL)

output = NULL
for (i in url_lst) { 
  x = as.data.frame(read_json(i))
  output = rbind(output,x)
 }
```

However, this results in an error:

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

As well, the code only produces 8 observations rather than 1200.

*Edit 2: Bill Ash's answer got me further than I was, but it looks like some values in the JSON data aren't allowing the code to be successful.

Bill Ash's code:

```
library(httr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
library(jsonlite)

ip_addresses <- core_members$ip_address

# a simple function
ip_locate <- function(your_vector_of_ip_addresses, access_key) {

  ip <- your_vector_of_ip_addresses

  map_df(ip, ~{
    out <- httr::GET(url = paste0("http://api.ipstack.com/", .,
                                  "?access_key=", access_key))
    resp <- fromJSON(httr::content(out, "text"), flatten = TRUE)
    tibble::tibble(ip = resp$ip, 
                   country = resp$country_name, 
                   region = resp$region_name, 
                   city = resp$city, 
                   zip = resp$zip, 
                   lat = resp$latitude, 
                   lng = resp$longitude)

  })

}


ip_info <- ip_locate(your_vector_of_ip_addresses = ip_addresses, 
                     access_key = "[access_key]")

# output

ip_info %>% 
  head()
```

Where the error begins

```
ip_info <- ip_locate(your_vector_of_ip_addresses = ip_addresses, 
                     access_key = "[access_key]")

Error: All columns in a tibble must be 1d or 2d objects:
* Column `zip` is NULL
9.
stop(cnd) 
8.
abort(error_column_must_be_vector(names_x[is_xd], classes)) 
7.
check_valid_cols(x) 
6.
lst_to_tibble(xlq$output, .rows, .name_repair, lengths = xlq$lengths) 
5.
tibble::tibble(ip = resp$ip, country = resp$country_name, region = resp$region_name, 
city = resp$city, zip = resp$zip, lat = resp$latitude, lng = resp$longitude) 
4.
.f(.x[[i]], ...) 
3.
map(.x, .f, ...) 
2.
map_df(ip, ~{
out <- httr::GET(url = paste0("http://api.ipstack.com/", 
    ., "?access_key=", access_key))
resp <- fromJSON(httr::content(out, "text"), flatten = TRUE) ... 
1.
ip_locate(your_vector_of_ip_addresses = ip_addresses, access_key = "[access_key]")
```

Because I only need the coordinates from these IP addresses, I believe this has been resolved. Hopefully, someone is willing to continue advising on this issue, but I won't be updating this any further.

Comment: `?read_json` says that `path`= is *"file on disk"*. Have you tried `stream_in(url(..))`?

Comment: @r2evans I did try that and it says that "Argument 'con' must be a connection". I'm not entirely sure how to remedy that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can pay for bulk lookup as well.

From there documentation page:

Bulk IP Lookup

The ipstack API also offers the ability to request data for multiple IPv4 or IPv6 addresses at the same time. In order to process IP addresses in bulk, simply append multiple comma-separated IP addresses to the API's base URL.

```
library(httr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
library(jsonlite)

# some ip addresses 
ip_addresses <- c("178.140.119.217", "68.37.21.125", "68.10.255.89")

# a simple function
ip_locate <- function(your_vector_of_ip_addresses, access_key) {

  ip <- your_vector_of_ip_addresses

  map_df(ip, ~{
    out <- httr::GET(url = paste0("http://api.ipstack.com/", .,
                    "?access_key=", access_key))
    resp <- fromJSON(httr::content(out, "text"), flatten = TRUE)
    tibble::tibble(ip = resp$ip, 
                   country = resp$country_name, 
                   region = resp$region_name, 
                   city = resp$city, 
                   zip = resp$zip, 
                   lat = resp$latitude, 
                   lng = resp$longitude)

  })

    }

# an example 
ip_info <- ip_locate(your_vector_of_ip_addresses = ip_addresses, 
          access_key = "had to edit out my key")

# output

ip_info %>% 
  head()

# A tibble: 3 x 7
  ip              country       region   city       zip      lat   lng
  <chr>           <chr>         <chr>    <chr>      <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 178.140.119.217 Russia        Moscow   Moscow     101001  55.8  37.6
2 68.37.21.125    United States Michigan Southgate  48195   42.2 -83.2
3 68.10.255.89    United States Virginia Chesapeake 23323   36.8 -76.3
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for answering, it looks like this is the solution I was looking for. I think the code is reacting negatively to the rest of the data, specifically the zip column, because I'm receiving an error. "Error: All columns in a tibble must be 1d or 2d objects:
* Column zip is NULL"

Comment: Read the documentation for ‘purrr::possibly’ and wrap it around tibble. Should be what you need to run for all of your ip addresses. Alternatively, you could try coercing the output variables to characters in tibble, or change map_df to map and then bindrows of your list. Hope this helps.

Comment: Will do, I tried reading tibble documentation, but wasn't getting much out of it.

Comment: Tibble is just a fancy dataframe if that helps. I think one of the purrr:: functions is what you need. Either ‘possibly(tibble %>%..... , NULL) ‘, or ‘try(tibble %>% ..., silent = T)’.